# trying to support python code in tcl

Tags: python, tcl, cython, swig

I'm new to all of this thing, and so please excuse me if i kinda did something stupid here. Treat me and explain to me as if i'm a total noob would be helpful.

I have a simple function written in python, filename `a.pyx`:-

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

def get_syspath():
    ret = sys.path
    print "Syspath:{}".format(ret)
    return ret
```

I want it to be able to be used by tcl.

I read thru the cython page, and followed.

I ran this:-

```
cython -o a.c a.pyx
```

I then ran this command to generate the object file `a.o`:-

```
gcc -fpic -c a.c -I/usr/local/include -I/tools/share/python/2.7.1/linux64/include/python2.7
```

And then ran this to generate the so file `a.so`:-

```
gcc -shared a.o -o a.so
```

when i load it from a tclsh, it failed.

```
$tclsh
% load ./a.so
couldn't load file "./a.so": ./a.so: undefined symbol: PyExc_RuntimeError
```

Am i taking the correct path here? If not, can please explain to me what went wrong, and what should I be doing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The object code needs to be linked to the libraries it depends on when you're building the loadable library. This means adding appropriate `-l...` options and possibly some `-L...` options as well. I'm guessing that the option will be something like `-lpython27` or something like that (which links to a `libpython27.so` somewhere on your library search path; the library search path is modified with the `-L...` options), ***but I don't know***. Paths will depend a lot on exactly how your system is set up and experimentation is likely required on your half.

It still probably won't work as a loadable library in Tcl. Tcl expects there to be a library initialisation function (in your case, it will look for `A_Init`) that takes a `Tcl_Interp*` as its only argument so that the library can install the commands it defines into the Tcl interpreter context. I would be astonished if Python made such a thing by default. It's not failing with that for you yet because the failures are still happening during the internal `dlopen()` call and not the `dlsym()` call, but I can confidently predict that you'll still face them.

The easiest way to “integrate” that sort of functionality is by running the command in a subprocess.

Here's the Python code you might use:

```python
import os
import sys

print sys.path
```

And here's the Tcl code to use it:

```tcl
set syspath [exec python /path/to/yourcode.py]
# If it is in the same directory as this script, use this:
#set syspath [exec python [file join [file dirname [info script]] yourcode.py]]
```

It's not the most efficient way, but it's super-easy to make it work since you don't have to solve the compilation and linking of the two languages. It's *programmer-efficient*…

Comment: hi @donal thx for the help. but what I actually need to do is more than that. I have a package which has classes of objects. I need to translate all of those into tcl usable package.  any hints for me on what or where I should be looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look at [`tclpython`](http://jfontain.free.fr/tclpython.htm) or [`libtclpy`](https://github.com/aidanhs/libtclpy).

Both allow calling Python code from Tcl.

But if you wanted to wrap things in a nicer way, e.g. have nicer already wrapped APIs, maybe you should also look at [Elmer](http://elmer.sourceforge.net/), which seems to aim at the task your attempting.